# ImageMagick - convert .svg .jpg

Tags: node.js, svg, imagemagick

Делаю превью для SVG в формате JPG в nodejs при помощи ImageMagick. Некоторые файлы ([пример](http:///jsdom/living/generated/HTMLAppletElement.js)) конвертируются в пустые прямоугольники. Проблема в самом ImageMagick - запускаю в консоли, результат тот же. Полагаю, все дело в размере SVG.
Можно ли это решить какими-нибудь параметрами ImageMagick? Какая есть альтернатива?

Comment: Зачем вы конвертируете векторную графику в растровую? Формат jpeg предназначен **только** для фотографий!

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, а в каком формате делать превью для SVG, если качество не важно, а размер критичен?

Comment: лучше уж тогда png. Он хоть и не векторный, но в нём сжатие будет лучше и потерь меньше при смене формата, именно потому что он изначально оптимизирован хранить изображения, состоящие из чётких отрезков, созданных на компьютере, как и svg. Jpeg же наоборот, лучше сжимает фотореалистичные изображения с плавными переходами, за счёт добавления в них шума, который на таких изображениях незаметен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел альтернативы: [convert-svg-to-jpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-svg-to-jpeg) и [svg2img](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2img). Пришлось повозиться с установкой, svg2img не захотел конвертировать в jpg без махинаций с новой версией canvas.